# Play video in Foreground services with notification Control

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Hey Everyone I am new in Android App development I want to play video in foreground service means when I press back button, home button or even in lock status audio from video should play in notification with the play, pause control I had tried but can't get proper result in a proper way, can anyone help me to do this operation. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

one of the bests lib for playing video is [exoplayer](https://exoplayer.dev/)

there is a good example for  [exoplayer and notification](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/playback-notifications-with-exoplayer-a2f1a18cf93b)